# Websockets on elixir code

Tags: sockets, websocket, elixir

I'm currently creating a chat using elixir. but anytime i try running the app, the websocket gives an error on sever console

```
The client's requested channel transport version "2.0.0" does not match server's version requirements of "~> 1.0"
```

And browser console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/socket/websocket token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJVc2VyOjMiLCJleHAiOjE1MDQ0OTE1NTQsImlhdCI6MTUwMTg5OTU1NCwiaXNzIjoiU2xpbmciLCJqdGkiOiIyNWY5NDZkNy1jNDg5LTRiYWMtYjJkNS0zZDA4OTdkNDU1ZWMiLCJuYmYiOjE1MDE4OTk1NTMsInBlbSI6e30sInN1YiI6IlVzZXI6MyIsInR5cCI6ImFjY2VzcyJ9.nh-DaQfY8OuI0EBE7lILFx6hjm6J_ZrynXHeOLr1-wM-fXnDakqrZUSN1XFQnr0x0KM9WFOkLEQnip5DcsKxXw&vsn=2.0.0' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your phoenix javascript library (dependency) is updated without notice. You should fix version so it is limited to less than 1.3.0 in package.json (if you are using npm) or bower.json if you are using bower to use old implementation, or use narrowtux solution if you downloaded js file manually. Or upgrade phoenix version.

Comment: Im using elixir. how do i do that? its specified {:phoenix, "~> 1.2.1"},

Comment: you said you are using websocket from browser, so you are using phoenix.js library. By default, when you create project with mix phoenix.new, package.json in project root will point this javascript phoenix.js dependency to file:deps/phoenix and that should work, but if someone changed that it could point to npmjs.org repo. Either point it back to default or set it as follows `"phoenix": "1.2.1",`. If frontend is another project, then do this change there in package.json file

Answer (score 0):

With Phoenix 1.3, a new version of the transport protocol was released. It seems that you've somehow included the new version of the javascript client in your project, but are still running on Phoenix 1.2.

As a workaround, you can copy and reference the old client script here: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.2/web/static/js/phoenix.js