# Phoenix - client requested channel transport error

Tags: phoenix-framework

While running my Phoenix app, I suddenly noticed an error being logged:

`The client's requested channel transport version "2.0.0" does not match server's version requirements of "~> 1.0"`

It appears after starting the server with `mix phoenix.server`:

```
[info] Running MyApp.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://localhost:4000
21 Nov 13:47:19 - info: compiled 4 files into app.js, copied robots.txt in 2.3 sec
[error] The client's requested channel transport version "2.0.0" does not match server's version requirements of "~> 1.0"
```

and then continues to log the error message every 10 seconds or so, regardless of whether or not I'm making any requests to the server.  Despite this, the app seems to run fine, but it'd be great to resolve this.

Can anyone shed any light on why this would've suddenly started happening, and what I can do to fix it?

Here's some config info from `mix.exs`:

```
def application do
 [mod: {MyApp, []},
  applications: [:phoenix, :phoenix_pubsub, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, :logger, :gettext,
                :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex, :comeonin]]
end

defp deps do
  [{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.1"},
   {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
   {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
   {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
   {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
   {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
   {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
   {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
   {:cors_plug, "~> 1.1"},
   {:comeonin, "~> 3.0"},
   {:guardian, "~> 0.14"},
   {:guardian_db, "~> 0.8.0"}]
end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45517636/websockets-on-elixir-code

Comment: @Dogbert thanks, friend

Comment: Oddly, I just started my Phoenix server and the error is not logging anymore. I didn't change anything yet.